# What sound symbolism related to masturbation exist ?

Tags: sound-symbolism

Ideophones are words that stand for instance for physical sensation,psychological states or even abstract ideas. 
For instance:

- niko niko    smile
- patan   the sensation of slamming a door
- honobono   the state of peacefullness
- kacha    sensation of sth. opening

Are there any sound symbolisms that can be used for sensations, events, psychological states related to masturbation ?

for instance:

- the onset of  ejaculation
- the pulling and pushing of the foreskin
- imagining of some absent person while performing
- the feeling of frustration  not being able to perform in a satisfying manner
- the state of alertness one could be caught
- pushing of sth. too big into the vagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

シコシコ is the usual sound of masturbation.

Comment: thank you, where did you found this information ?

Comment: I live in japan